# Override UITextView Undo

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsundomanager

I'd like my subclass of UITextView to stop using it's undo / redo method, so that my custom undo method can take over:

```
NSUndoManager registerUndoWithTarget:selector:object:
```

I have yet to work out how to add redo operations to the stack. (despite reading [Undo Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/UndoManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000205-CJBDJCCJ))  Perhaps someone could point me in the right direction?

Comment: I suppose one solution would be to implement my own undo manager using the accelerometer, custom undo / redo stacks, ect... but this doesn't seem like the way to go

Answer (score 1):

I went and re-read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/iPhoneUndo.html), and the solution became apparent.  I'll explain how this works for those who struggled as I did.

To implement a custom NSUndoManager in a UITextView subclass:

> 1. Override the NSUndoManager property & synthesize

```
@property (retain) NSUndoManager *undoManager;
```

> 2. Initialize NSUndoManager

```
self.undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
```

> 3. Register Undo Action before change occurs

```
[self.undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(someHandleUndoMethod:) object:(somePre-ChangeObject)];
```

Note: Redo actions are automatically taken care of.